# How can I reuse a block multiple times?

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I render a block multiple times within a view in a twig template? Currently I do have a block, let's call it `something` defined in an included (via `render`) twig file. I then include it at the layout-twig file using the following:

```
{% block something %}{% endblock %}
```

Everything is fine, however as soon as I call this tag a second time, I get the following error message:

```
The block 'something ' has already been defined in "::layout.html.twig"
```

Therefore: How can I render a block multiple times?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The notation you're showing us is for defining and rendering a block. Rendering only is done this way:

```
{{ block('blockName') }}
```

Comment: Thanks - I currently used the notation of having a default value, which is then overwritten in child templates. Thx!

Comment: This syntax is not applicable to .tera templates in Rust. no criticism, but it might interest people searching for the same thing as me right now