# Page Loads Slowly

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I have an admin panel that the admin can use to edit events; so I fetch the events from the DB and display them there for the admin to edit.
And this takes **1.5min on average**.

Here are the relevant files:

### Controller

```
    public function editEvent($result = null)
    {
        if ($this->adminIsLoggedIn()) {

            $db = new DB();

            $events = $db->getEvents();
            $venues = $db->getVenues();
            $types = $db->getEventTypes();

            echo $this->twig->render('editEvent.twig', array('result'=>$result, 'events'=>$events, 'venues'=>$venues, 'types'=>$types));

        } else {
            $this->login();
        }
    }
```

### The html page (I am using Twig)

```
{% extends "master.twig" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="right_col" role="main">
        <div class="">
            <div class="page-title">
                <div class="title_left">
                    <h3>Edit Event</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="x_panel">
                        <div class="x_title">
                            <h2>Click on the fields to edit</h2>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x_content">

                            {% if result.success == true %}
                                <h3 style="color: forestgreen">{{ result.message }}</h3>
                            {% else %}
                                <h3 style="color: tomato">{{ result.message }}</h3>
                            {% endif %}

                            <form action="/admin/editEvent" method="post">
                                <table id="datatable"
                                       class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive-utilities jambo_table">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Title</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Source URL</th>
                                        <th>Type</th>
                                        <th>Start Date</th>
                                        <th>End Date</th>
                                        <th>Date Created</th>
                                        <th>Start Time</th>
                                        <th>End Time</th>
                                        <th>Venue</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                    {% for event in events %}

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="events[]" value="{{ event.id }}"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input style="border: 1px solid lightblue;" type="text" name="title[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.title}}">
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea style="border: 1px solid lightblue;" class="mce_ta" type="text" name="description[{{ event.id }}]">{{ event.description }}</textarea>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input style="border: 1px solid lightblue;" type="text" name="source_url[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.source_url }}">
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="type_id[{{ event.id }}]" class="form-control">
                                                    <option selected value="{{ event.type_id }}">{{ event.type_name }}</option>
                                                    {% for type in types %}
                                                        <option value="{{ type.id }}">{{ type.type_name }}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input class="event_start_date date-picker" type="text" name="event_start_date[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.event_start_date }}"></td>
                                            <td><input class="event_end_date date-picker" type="text" name="event_end_date[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.event_end_date }}"></td>
                                            <td><input class="creation_date date-picker" type="text" name="event_date[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.creation_date }}"></td>
                                            <td><input class="time_pick clockpicker" type="text" name="start_time[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.start_time }}"></td>
                                            <td><input class="time_pick clockpicker" type="text" name="end_time[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.end_time }}"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="venue_id[{{ event.id }}]" class="form-control">
                                                    <option selected value="{{ event.venue_id }}">{{ event.venue_name }}</option>
                                                    {% for venue in venues %}
                                                        <option value="{{ venue.id }}">{{ venue.venue_name }}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </td>


                                        </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <div class="form-group-lg" style="margin: 10px auto;">
                                    <button style="margin: 30px auto;" type="submit"
                                            class="btn btn-warning btn-block pull-left">
                                        Edit Selected Events
                                    </button>
                                </div>

                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block scripts %}

    <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.date-picker').daterangepicker({
                singleDatePicker: true,
                calender_style: "picker_4",
                locale: {

                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                }
            }, function (start, end, label) {
                console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- /bootstrap-daterangepicker -->

    <!-- clockpicker -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.time_pick').clockpicker({
                placement: 'left',
                align: 'top',
                autoclose: true,
                'default': '21:30'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- /clockpicker -->

{% endblock scripts %}
```

### And the DB query - Retrieves 330 rows

```
public function getEvents()
    {
        $result = array();
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
SELECT Events.id AS id, Events.title AS title, Events.description AS description, Events.source_url AS source_url, Events.type_id AS type_id, EventTypes.type_name AS type_name, Events.event_start_date AS event_start_date, Events.event_end_date AS event_end_date, Events.creation_date AS creation_date, TIME_FORMAT(start_time, '%H:%i') AS start_time, TIME_FORMAT(end_time, '%H:%i') AS end_time, Events.venue_id AS venue_id, Venues.venue_name AS venue_name
FROM $this->dbname.Events
INNER JOIN $this->dbname.EventTypes  
ON Events.type_id = EventTypes.id
INNER JOIN $this->dbname.Venues  
ON Events.venue_id = Venues.id
ORDER BY creation_date DESC, id DESC;");
            $stmt->execute();

            // set the resulting array to associative
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

The query takes an average of 2.5 secs so this is not the problem.
I think the problem is the loop in the html page that displays all the events one by one. Namely:

```
  {% for event in events %}

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="events[]" value="{{ event.id }}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="border: 1px solid lightblue;" type="text" name="title[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.title}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea style="border: 1px solid lightblue;" class="mce_ta" type="text" name="description[{{ event.id }}]">{{ event.description }}</textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="border: 1px solid lightblue;" type="text" name="source_url[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.source_url }}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="type_id[{{ event.id }}]" class="form-control">
                <option selected value="{{ event.type_id }}">{{ event.type_name }}</option>
                {% for type in types %}
                    <option value="{{ type.id }}">{{ type.type_name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input class="event_start_date date-picker" type="text" name="event_start_date[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.event_start_date }}"></td>
        <td><input class="event_end_date date-picker" type="text" name="event_end_date[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.event_end_date }}"></td>
        <td><input class="creation_date date-picker" type="text" name="event_date[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.creation_date }}"></td>
        <td><input class="time_pick clockpicker" type="text" name="start_time[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.start_time }}"></td>
        <td><input class="time_pick clockpicker" type="text" name="end_time[{{ event.id }}]" value="{{ event.end_time }}"></td>
        <td>
            <select name="venue_id[{{ event.id }}]" class="form-control">
                <option selected value="{{ event.venue_id }}">{{ event.venue_name }}</option>
                {% for venue in venues %}
                    <option value="{{ venue.id }}">{{ venue.venue_name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>


    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You have 2 other queries in your controller? Are they not also relevant?

Comment: How many records are being retrieved? How many in the database?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes but they don't take much time. If you look inside the loop in the HTML file, I have two other loops (types and venues) whose values I take from these two queries.

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Yes I forgot to mention it. I retrieve all of the entries in the DB; which means 330

Comment: @padawanTony why do u retrive all that number in the same time? why not paging the results? assigning `LIMIT` in sql query

Comment: 330 rows is an insignificant number for it to be running for  more than a couple of seconds

Comment: @xYuri Very good question! I haven't done it before so I don't know how. I guessed that this is the solution and I am looking for the right way to deal with this error. So if you want, create an answer with guidance on how to do it (or tutorials to check)

Comment: You process the venues and types arrays each time you process an event, to get exactly the same result each time. Can you not create these 2 dropdowns ONCE and save each in a variable, then just drop that var into the `<select>`

Comment: ill post my own paging `func` in a min

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are right of course. But I don't really understand how to do it. Would you like to create an answer with that?

Comment: @xYuri Even better.

Comment: Remember 330 * (10 types + 10 venues) = 6600 iterations, but even that should only take a matter of seconds

Comment: @RiggsFolly agreed. Another thing that takes a lot of time is the integration of the `tinymce` editor in every `description` field of every event

Comment: In that case, look at the Network Tab of the browsers debugger. Maybe the issue is not with your twig code, but something in the javascript in the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly even when I completely remove `tinymce`, it still takes around 35 secs to load. I am trying to find out how I can copy the information form the Network Tab to paste here.

Comment: for more info, explains, examples google "`php mysql` pagination"

Comment: Please show us the SQL statements in isolation, but with values filled in.

Comment: [_Pagination via OFFSET is evil_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) (and how to improve on it).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the pagination suggestion, you should definitely look at building those two selects once at the beginning (as a Twig block) and then reusing it for every iteration. This post tells you how to do that:

[How can I reuse a block multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616049/how-can-i-reuse-a-block-multiple-times)

Food for thought:

- Do you have an index in the database?
- Do you really need the inner joins or does that just make things easier?
- Couldn't you only load tinymce for an element when someone clicks it?
- Couldn't you only load datePicker for an element when someone clicks it?

Is the machine you are using so slow?

Hope that helps,
Taff

Comment: Great answer. Please also include resources (ex: tutorials) on loading a library only when the user takes an action. Maybe also explain your `food for thought` questions a bit more

Comment: I don't have any resources as such, but that is how I would go about it. Maybe try Google? Tinymce example: http://archive.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/load_on_demand.php I'm not sure how I can explain my questions further but feel free to post specific questions if you any.